Confusion regarding the graph of half an ellipse
So, starting with $E:4x^2+y^2+8x-4y-8=0$, the ellipse is given by $\frac{(x+1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-2)^2}{16}=1$. Then, solving for $y$, I got:
$$y=\pm \sqrt{-4x^2-8x+12}-2$$

Maybe is a silly question, but If I'm asked to describe analytically the expression $E$, I would do it over a distinct ellipse. As You can see in the image. What I want to understand is why this happening, and notice that adding $+2$ instead of $-2$, the both halves match the given ellipse. But why? Can you explain me? And... would it be preferable to treat that as the ellipse or take both halves as functions, for an analytically description of the curve?

Well, first of all, you've made a mistake in solving for $y$, and the $-2$ really should be a $+2$.

Do you want to know why is it forming an ellipse? As @MishaLavrov said, it should be a +2 in your expression for $y$.  For that, $$y=\pm \sqrt{-4x^2-8x+12}+2$$ will return two semi-ellipses, centred at $(-1,2)$ and one will be the mirror image of the other across the mirror line $y=2$. They will exactly overlap your ellipse ofcourse
